# Unir linhas de uma coluna Python

Tags: python

Estou tentando agrupar meus dados que estão em uma coluna. Tenho 43184 linhas de dados, e preciso agrupar eles a cada 60 dados, no caso fazer uma media a cada 60. Tentei fazer e não gerou erro porém quando eu vou visualizar a quantidade de dados tem mais dados, então acredito que não tenha calculado a média, pois teria que ter uma base de 720 dados e gerou muito mais que isso. Alguem pode me ajudar a ver o que posso estar colocando errado no codigo?

```
media = []


for i in range (0,len(press),59):


for media1 in press:
    
    
    media1= np.mean(press[i:i+59])

    media.append(media1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu segundo for é desnecessário. Simulei um DF com o mesmo tanto de linhas aqui, e deu uma lista de médias com 720 elementos.

```
df_t = pd.DataFrame(list(range(0, 43184)), columns = ['column'])

media = []
for i in range(0, len(df_t), 60):
    media.append(np.mean(df_t[i:i+59]['column']))
```

Você também precisa ir até o elemento 60 no for, para que ele percorra um caminho entre 0 e 59. Caso o contrário, ele vai até 58, e isso deve ser um dos motivos que gera uma lista com tamanho maior que 720;

Comment: Muito obrigada, tirei o outro for e deu certo. Valeeu :D

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa utilizando o groupby do pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Criando o data frame de teste

```
dados = pd.DataFrame({'Dados':np.random.randint(1,100, 43184)})
```

Calculando a média com mean diretamente

```
dados.groupby(dados.index // 60).mean()
```

Ou utilizando o aggregate

```
dados.groupby(dados.index // 60).agg({'Dados':'mean'})
```